# MouseWheelListener block scroll

Tags: java, scroll, block, jeditorpane

```
    JEditorPane.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

When I add these lines - in the JEditorPane scroll stops working. How can it be cured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post more of your code to get better help. However, this simple demo worked fine for me (i.e. scrolling still works after adding the `MouseWheelListener` to the `JScrollPane`).

```
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Frame
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( );
        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane( );

        String t = "";
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++ ) t += "t";

        pane.setText( t );

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( pane );

        scroll.addMouseWheelListener( new MouseWheelListener( )
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved( MouseWheelEvent e )
            {
                System.out.println( "Scroll" );
            }
        });

        frame.add( scroll );
        frame.setSize( 400, 400 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how MouseWheelEvents are dispatched in Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html

In short, events are delivered to the topmost component under cursor and in swing, in most cases mouse wheel events are handled by JScrollPane. JEditorPane contains a scrollpane inside of it, so if you add a listener on JEditorPane, JScrollPane will stop receiving events. That's why you have the problem. It's better to add a listener to JScrollPane instead.

Comment: but if add a listener to JScrollPane - in the JScrollPane scroll stops working. I need to scroll always worked. I need to scroll was working whenever and wherever. Maybe there is a way to get an event without blocking?

Comment: I have a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane. (The JTextArea's actual parent is a JViewPort and the JViewPort's parent is a JScrollPane.) I add a MouseWheelListener to the JTextArea's getParent().getParent() which is the JScrollPane and I get both default scrolling actions and my custom MouseWheelEvents. (I use a mouseWheelEvent.isControlDown() to zoom in/out the contents in the JTextPane (by increasing or decreasing the font size)